# A change of sign in the electron-hole second quantization form

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, semiconductor-physics, many-body, second-quantization

It is common to see people do a change of sign in the so called electron-hole representation,

namely,

$$
b^{\dagger}_{-k}=a_{v,k}
$$

similar argument also seen in 1992 mattuck's book "guide to feynman's diagrams" pp.138, eq.7.78b.

Can somebody explain what is the physical meaning of changing the sign of momentum, since it make a difference in specific calculations, clearly it is not just a convention, meanwhile it seems to change momentum conservation law in a way that is unambiguous in the electron-electron representation..

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what OP is really asking (v2) but try this explanation:

Imagine that there is a hole in the (almost filled) [Dirac sea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_sea), i.e. that there is an unoccupied state in momentum space at some momentum $k$. That would mean that the system is missing momentum $k$ as compared to the undisturbed Dirac sea. Or in other words, one may say that the hole carries momentum $-k$.

More formally, the point is: Which state does one choose to play the role of the "vacuum state" $|\Omega \rangle$ in the second quantized model? In condensed matter systems, it is vastly simpler and more useful to let the filled Dirac sea represents the $|\Omega \rangle$ than, say, the empty Dirac sea.